# Detect a specific embedded script and remove it?

Tags: javascript

On my site, I give users the option to embed their own scripts.  Most people use this for GA or FB pixels.  However, There are some vendor scripts that are breaking the user's page.  Is there a way I can see if a specific script is embedded by a keyword and then remove it ?

Comment: You can select scripts based on the URL, className, or ID. Can you just do a check for all third party scripts? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

By the time you detect whether a certain script has been loaded, it would be too late to remove since it's already in memory and has been executed.

The only way to prevent the download and execution of a script in someone's browser would be to use a 3rd party browser extension (adblockers are a good example of that).